# Getting number of rows affected by an UPDATE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

variations of this question has been asked on SO and on many blogs but none offers a straight-forward answer. I hope there is one.
I am updating PostgreSQL 9.0 (from CodeIgniter, PHP framework):

```
$sql_order = "UPDATE meters SET billed=true"; 
$query = $this->db->query($sql_order);
```

I simply need a count of rows that were affected by the update, but there seems to be no way to do this with PostgreSQL. The query is now returning a boolean - true.
The manual and web talk refer to the `RETURNING` syntax, to `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, and to a default return type from `UPDATE`. I haven't been able to get any of these to work. 
Is there a straightforward way of getting rows affect count without having to embed this simple operation into a procedure or transaction.

Comment: What language are you working in?  PHP?  Is this part of a script inside a PostgreSQL function like PL/php: http://www.commandprompt.com/community/plphp/ or an external PHP interpreter connecting to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java I would have used the following:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
int rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE ...");
```

In PHP I believe [`pg_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.pg-affected-rows.php) is the way. And in your particular case [`$this->db->affected_rows()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)